# Calling Spring beans from VB.net

Tags: vb.net, spring

I have a already created library that i developed in java using Spring.
It would be good if i could just call the Spring Beans from a new application that is in VB.net and get the job done.

is it possible or do you think  i would need to implement the functionality in Spring library to be done in VB.net?

Comment: Calling java from .Net isn't going to work unless you wrap it inside a  web service (SOAP or REST or …). You would have to put some kind of language agnostic interface in between. Calling directly will not work.

Comment: Can you link me to some example that i can refer to. Much Thanks .